# What is equivalent Django syntax for SQL query consists of inner join, count, where?

Tags: sql-server, django, python-3.x

I have a DB which have tables like below:

```
class Maindata(models.Model):
    index = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    dco = models.IntegerField(db_column='DCO', blank=True, null=True)
    patient = models.IntegerField(db_column='PATIENT', blank=True, null=True)
    primary = models.IntegerField(db_column='PRIMARY', blank=True, null=True)
    fsdate = models.TextField(db_column='FSDATE', blank=True, null=True)
    uhpi = models.TextField(db_column='UHPI', blank=True, null=True)
    uhpiold = models.TextField(db_column='UHPIold', blank=True, null=True)
    wghnum = models.TextField(db_column='WGHNUM', blank=True, null=True)
    idstatus = models.TextField(db_column='IDstatus', blank=True, null=True)
    fsc2date = models.TextField(db_column='FSC2DATE', blank=True, null=True)
    iopat = models.TextField(db_column='IOPAT', blank=True, null=True)
    anndate = models.TextField(db_column='ANNDATE', blank=True, null=True)
    site =  models.ForeignKey('Sitelut', db_column='SITE', to_field='code', blank=True, null=True, related_name='site')
```

and Chemotherapy table:

```
   class Chemotherapy(models.Model):
    index = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    patient = models.IntegerField(db_column='PATIENT', blank=True, null=True)
    primary = models.IntegerField(db_column='PRIMARY', blank=True, null=True)
    episode = models.IntegerField(db_column='EPISODE', blank=True, null=True)
    material = models.ForeignKey('Chemomateriallut', db_column='MATERIAL', blank=True, null=True, related_name='material')
    stdate = models.TextField(db_column='STDATE', blank=True, null=True)
    enddate = models.TextField(db_column='ENDDATE', blank=True, null=True)
    method = models.ForeignKey('Chemomethodlut', db_column='METHOD', blank=True, null=True, related_name='method')
```

I'm trying to perform a query which connect the two tables and get some information (below is my query):

```
Select count(*), Chemotherapy.Material, Chemotherapy.METHOD from 
Chemotherapy inner join Maindata on Chemotherapy.Patient = Maindata.Patient and Chemotherapy.[Primary] = Maindata.[Primary] where ((Maindata.site) = '1749')
group by Chemotherapy.MATERIAL, Chemotherapy.METHOD
```

Initially, I used filter and annotate. But then, I realise that it doesn't return the same result (as I don't check whether it has the same primary id).

My initial syntax is as below:

```
Chemotherapy.objects.filter(
    patient__in=Maindata.objects.filter(site='1749')
.values('patient').distinct()).select_related().values('material', 'method')
.annotate(dcount=Count('material', 'method'))
```

How do I fix this query?

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL query is working as intended you may use Django ORM raw SQL option:

```
query = "Select count(*), Chemotherapy.Material, Chemotherapy.METHOD from ..."
Chemotherapy.objects.raw(query)
```